# Representar el tiempo en el eje de abscisas con Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

estoy queriendo graficar una relación entre dos cantidades (una medida y otra modelada), los datos por cada día. Los tengo en un data frame indexado por fecha, lo que estoy precisando es que me muestre en el eje x la fecha no la magnitud de la cantidad medida.

El código que genero, por ejemplo para el data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'medido': [3, 2, 3, 9, 10, 6],'modelo': [5, 5, 6, 12, 14, 13]}, index=pd.date_range(start='2017/09/01', end='2017/09/6', freq='1D'))
```

si grafico así:

```
df.plot.scatter(x= 'medido', y= 'modelo', s = 1)
```

obtengo bien el gráfico, pero quisiera que en el eje de las abscisas figure la fecha no una sucesión de 2 al 10. Intenté con esto:

```
df.plot.scatter(x= 'medido', y= 'modelo', s = 1, xticks = [i for i in df.index])
```

si bien no indica error, me muestra [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
L
Lo ideal sería que me muestre en el eje x, y para cada relación la fecha en cuestión.

Un error que no pude entender a qué se refiere usando directamente matplotlib:

```
    etiqueta_x = [x for x in df.index]
xlabels = []
for i in etiqueta_x:
    xlabels.append(datetime.strftime(i, '%Y-%m-%d'))

plt.plot(df.medido, df.modelo, 'o')

plt.xticks([i for i in xlabels], rotation=45)
```

Pensando que quizás no añadía las etiquetas, por ser un timestamp, lo convertí a cadenas de texto, pero obtengo el error:

```
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Alguna idea?
Gracias!

EDITADO:

Añado una gráfica sobre lo que necesito:
[image: En el eje X tener las fechas, no el valor medido]
Luego con esto puedo trazar algún ajuste lineal, que no es problema, sino que necesito ver en qué fechas no ajusta bien el modelo, los números indicados en los círculos representan cantidad de imágenes ya que de esa manera puedo saber si determinado día tuvo tantas imágenes. O sea ir a buscar más facilmente qué pasó con los primeros días.

Comment: Te he dejado la respuesta Dario, Sí necesitas por obligación una nube de putnos, házmelo saber y te lo pongo en scatter. :)

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación Alberto, necesariamente sí preciso hacerlo por scatter o bien graficar el modelo en función de lo medido ya que tengo que ver qué tan bien se comporta el modelo, y luego hacer un ajuste lineal y analizar los parámetros estadísticos. PAra el caso en que tengo datos diarios, no serían más de 30 aunque también lo tengo que hacer anual  ver cómo se comporta el modelo.

Comment: Sí, claro! por eso normalmente se suele usar el diagrama de barras, en este caso puedes ver en la respuesta, como el modelo, está prediciendo siempre por encima de la realidad, ya que la linea naranja que representa el modelo, está por encima de los datos reales (azul). De todas formas si te es más sencillo en scatter, te he ampliado la respuesta, para que tengas también un scatter :)

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Alberto, añadí una gráfica sobre lo que esperaría (excepto claro por el problema que no puedo añadir como etiquetas las fechas al eje X).

Comment: Lo siento, pero no consigo entender lo que quieres hacer. En esta última imagen que has subido, dónde debería aparecer la fecha exactamente?

Comment: Hola Alberto, publiqué una respuesta y solución al problema con la gráfica que aproximadamente quería. Si bien quisiera solamente que aparezca la fecha en el eje X sección inferior solamente, lo solucioné manteniendo las unidades de los datos  y añadí en el eje X superior la fecha (aunque sólo el día)

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado esa solución!! Por otro lado simplemente solo por si te es de ayuda mi aclaración. Cada eje solo puede contener una variable, ya que un eje representa un valor de una dimensión. Por lo tanto no puedes poner 2 variables en un mismo eje, por ello es imposible poner la variable tiempo y la variable medido en el eje de las X, tienes que elegir o una u otra. Nunca podrán ser las dos!! Si quieres poner tiempo, necesitas quitar medido y viceversa. 1/2

Comment: La solución que tú has hecho es correcta! Al solo poder representar una variable (dimensión) por eje, te ves forzado a crear otro eje, para representar otra variable (en este caso el eje superior con la fecha). De esta forma tienes en el eje "y" lo que ha dado tú modelo y en el "x" la realidad, y arriba el tiempo. *
**Pero no puedes poner dos variables (medido y tiempo) en un mismo eje**. Otra solución que no aparece y que podría ser. Es crear un gráfico tridimensional (en 3D) y crear un eje Z que represente el tiempo. En ese caso en vez de una linea ajustando tus datos tendrías un hiperplano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encontré la manera en la cual el eje X tenga por etiquetas las fechas de los datos y no las unidades de los datos, sino que encontré otra forma en la que convivan ambas, utilizando el método twiny() de matplotlib-pyplot, a continuación detallo el código que finalmente utilizé:

```
x = np.array(df_diario.medido)
y = np.array(df_diario.modelo)
fig = plt.figure()
comparativa = fig.add_subplot(111)
comparativa.plot(x, y, 'o')
comparativa.set_ylabel('Modelo [$Wh/m^2$]', fontfamily = 'serif')
comparativa.set_xlabel('Medido [$Wh/m^2$]', fontfamily = 'serif')
eje_fechas = comparativa.twiny()
eje_fechas.plot(x, y, 'o')
eje_fechas.set_xlim([1,calendar.monthlen(anno, int(mes_estac))+1])
plt.grid(axis ='both')
plt.title('JPTv1 ' + str(anno) + ' ' + mes_estac + '\n' + lugar)
# ajuste lineal
reg_lineal = stats.linregress(x, y)
R = reg_lineal[2]
R2 = R**2
ajuste = fig.add_subplot(111)
ajuste.plot(x, reg_lineal[0]*x+reg_lineal[1], '-', label = r'$R^2 = $' + str(R2))
plt.legend()
```

El método twiny() añade otra etiqueta en el eje X, en la parte superior, lo solucioné utilizando la misma función (se puede utilizar otra que tenga distintas unidades por ejemplo o no) ya que sólo quiero que me añada una etiqueta con la fecha del dato. Si se quisiera otra etiqueta en el eje Y se hace lo mismo sólo que con el método twinx().
Luego añado el ajuste lineal.
En la gráfica adjunta se ve en el eje X inferior las unidades del dato medido y en el superior la fecha para ese dato.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien no es tal como quisiera, me conforma en este momento mostrar sólo la fecha (día) puesto que en el título ya le añado el año y el mes.

Por mi parte doy por solucionado el problema.

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo no usaría un scatter, ya que con más datos puedes tener una malgama de puntos, que puede ser dificíl de interpretar. usaría un **diagrama de lineas** y lo crearía con series. Si tienes los indices en formato de fecha, como tú has hecho, **Las series funcionan muy bien con el resto de librerías para datos temporales**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.medido.plot() #ploteamos la linea con los datos reales
df.modelo.plot() #ploteamos la linea con nuestras predicciones

#añadimos algo de decoración
plt.title('Predicción modelo')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('lo que estemos midiendo')
plt.legend()
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: plot de matplotlib]

La costumbre es verlo con un diagrame de lineas, donde puedes ver como tu modelo siempre predice por encima de los valores reales.

Si por alguna razón, te es obligatorio representar el modelo con puntos en vez de con lineas, simplemente puedes cambiar el estilo utilizando `style='.'`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime 

df.medido.plot(style='.') 
df.modelo.plot(style='.') 

#añadimos algo de decoración
plt.title('Predicción modelo')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('lo que estemos midiendo')
#Ampliamos el eje de las X
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2017, 8, 31), datetime.date(2017, 9, 7)])
plt.legend()
```

y el resultado sería con puntos.

[image: Scatter plot]